# Error with mod_wsgi

Tags: mod-wsgi

I got the following error in logs:

```
Queue timeout expired for WSGI daemon process
```

How can I resolve it?
I use Django 1.7.1 with mod_wsgi.

`queue-timeout` is set to 45 in conf file.

This is part of my httpd.conf, that deals with threads.
How should I change values, so that it works?
I think that one thread is not enough.
Is 5 a big number?

```
<IfModule mpm_worker_module>
<IfDefine !ONE_PROCESS>
ServerLimit 2
ThreadLimit 10
StartServers 1
MaxClients 20
MinSpareThreads 10
MaxSpareThreads 10
ThreadsPerChild 10
</IfDefine>
<IfDefine ONE_PROCESS>
ServerLimit 1
ThreadLimit 1
StartServers 1 
MaxClients 1
MinSpareThreads 1
MaxSpareThreads 1
ThreadsPerChild 1
</IfDefine>
MaxRequestsPerChild 0
ThreadStackSize 262144
</IfModule>

<IfModule mpm_event_module>
<IfDefine !ONE_PROCESS>
ServerLimit 2
ThreadLimit 10
StartServers 1
MaxClients 20
MinSpareThreads 10
MaxSpareThreads 10
ThreadsPerChild 10
</IfDefine>
<IfDefine ONE_PROCESS>
ServerLimit 1
ThreadLimit 1
StartServers 1
MaxClients 1
MinSpareThreads 1
MaxSpareThreads 1
ThreadsPerChild 1
</IfDefine>
MaxRequestsPerChild 0
ThreadStackSize 262144
</IfModule>
```

Comment: How many threads is your daemon process group configured for? A single thread, the default, or something else? What is the maximum amount of time you realistically expect your requests to complete in? Do you have any particular long running requests? Also confirm whether you are using mod_wsgi-express or using mod_wsgi direct yourself with Apache.

Comment: I'm using mod_wsgi express as you taught me. (remember thread mod_wsgi + webfaction)? Realistically, i expect to be at most 10-15 seconds. threads=5 (this is default in httpd.conf) Also, see edited question.

Comment: That you are getting a queue timeout means that your request threads have likely blocked on something and you have used up all the available capacity. Subsequent requests coming in are then backlogging and never get a chance to be served. Eventually they time out and and error returned. So your requests are taking a lot longer than you expect.

Comment: As to your value of 5 for the number of threads, I don't see that. I read the auto generated configuration as creating 10 threads per process with maximum of 2 process. In your case this would be overridden in the shell script that was setup for you to generate the configuration. Change the value given to the ``--threads`` option. Then rerun the shell script to regenerate the configuration and then restart the Apache server using ``apachectl``.

Comment: How much threads should I set? Also, you said that requests are taking longer than I expect. What if 20 simultaneous requests come and each take 10 seconds to complete. How this is queued?

Comment: Requests are handled on first come first serve basis. If you have 20 requests arrive all about the same time and only have the capacity for handling 20 at a time, then one they start to be handled no other request can be. Those requests will sit there waiting in Apache to be passed to the WSGI application daemon process to be handled, or worst case sit waiting to be connected to Apache itself. When a spare request thread in the WSGI application is freed up, the next request will be handled. If all take 10 seconds, then all those subsequent requests will be delayed until backlog cleared.

Comment: I can only guess how many threads you need to handle the throughput of requests you have and for that I would need a lot more information than you are presenting here. You need to have some sort of monitoring in place. One specific metric that can be extracted from mod_wsgi is a capacity utilisation metric, showing how busy the WSGI application is and whether it is overloaded. It is too hard to explain here what you have to do for that as this is not a discussion forum.

Comment: Thank you. Why can't I set 20 threads? What is the danger of setting too much threads?

Comment: You already are using 20 threads across the two daemon processes being set up. That is, you are using processes=2 and threads=10. Increasing threads per process too much is bad if running CPU intensive tasks in the daemon processes. You are better off creating another process rather than adding threads. But then you have to contend with running out of overall memory if in a memory constrained environment. Reality is that for your application WebFaction is probably a poor choice, you need a greater memory limit, or more performance host.

Comment: What hosting will you advise?

Comment: Only you really know what the requirements are you have. Or at least only you have the ability to work it out. You need to know what memory requirements are, what capacity requirement you have based on throughput and response time, and what sort of CPU processing power you need based on whether what you are doing is CPU or I/O intensive.

Comment: I know requirements, but what are overall options on the internet? I thought WebFaction is good.